# Spring 5 & Encoding settings

Tags: java, spring, utf-8

I using Spring 5. Have problems with encoding, like this:

> ÐÐµÑ ÑÐ°ÐºÐ¾Ð³Ð¾ Ð±ÑÐµÐ½Ð´Ð°: 1000. ÐÐ¾Ð¶Ð°Ð»ÑÐ¹ÑÑÐ°, Ð¿ÑÐ¾Ð²ÐµÑÑÑÐµ Ð·Ð°Ð¿ÑÐ¾Ñ.

I tried to fix encoding this way:

```
@Configuration
public class AppInit extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
        addEncodingFilter(servletContext);
        super.onStartup(servletContext);
    }

...

private void addEncodingFilter(ServletContext servletContext) {
        CharacterEncodingFilter characterEncodingFilter = new CharacterEncodingFilter();
        characterEncodingFilter.setEncoding("UTF-8");
        characterEncodingFilter.setForceEncoding(true);

        EnumSet<DispatcherType> dispatcherTypes
                = EnumSet.of(DispatcherType.REQUEST, DispatcherType.FORWARD, DispatcherType.ERROR);

        FilterRegistration.Dynamic characterEncoding
                = servletContext.addFilter("characterEncoding", characterEncodingFilter);
        characterEncoding.addMappingForUrlPatterns(dispatcherTypes, true, "/*");
        characterEncoding.setAsyncSupported(true);
    }
}
```

but have no result. Please, give me ready solution how to set encoding for Spring 5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution was:

```
@Bean
public MessageSource messageSource() {
    ResourceBundleMessageSource source = new ResourceBundleMessageSource();
    source.setBasename("i18n/messages");
    source.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
    return source;
}
```

I needed simply to set default encoding for i18n files.

Comment: I tried this one, but it dioesn't work for me. When I submit a form directly I still get tofu strings.

Answer (score 1):

Try using spring Beans.

```
@Bean
public FilterRegistrationBean filterRegistrationBean() {
    FilterRegistrationBean registrationBean = new FilterRegistrationBean();
    CharacterEncodingFilter encodingFilter = new CharacterEncodingFilter();
    encodingFilter.setEncoding("UTF-8");
    encodingFilter.setForceEncoding(true);
    registrationBean.setFilter(encodingFilter);
    registrationBean.addUrlPatterns("/*");
    return registrationBean;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but it's about Spring Boot. Have idea how to make it without it?

Comment: Do you use maven or gradle in your project?

Comment: It may not be a Spring problem.

Comment: I use gradle project

Comment: It didn't help. Can you post your previous answer?

Comment: Ok, i changed it back